# Debian 9 - Apache 2.4.25 - Messages Error

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.4, web-server

I have installed Apache Web Server into Debian 9 OS.

When the service is running in the log file shows these messages errors:

> [Mon Mar 26 10:55:37.169653 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5361:tid 139891733357760] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   [Mon Mar 26 10:55:43.514147 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5479:tid 140226250499264] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.2l configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Mon Mar 26 10:55:43.514310 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5479:tid 140226250499264] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Exactly What does it mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in that message. It's just an informational message (a notice) that the server has received a signal to shut down and did so cleanly. Afterwards it was started again.

This was either triggered by a user (for example after editing the configuration files of the server) or by a update of the Apache package.